# A curved background with css

Tags: html, css

I want to recreate the curved background for this project i want to work on, how can i go about it?

[image: IMAGE FOR THE BACKGROUND]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71797190/8620333

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `clip-path` css property.

Comment: Please could you show me how to achieve this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).